# How to print out two variables in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, arm

For my program, it will asks user to key in a positive number and it will subsequently do the double factorial calculation and print out the result. However, what I currently have is that the output will be printed out as "Result = 15" when I keyed in 5. I want to print the output as "Result of 5 = 15". How can I do it?

---

```
.global main                @ start of the assembly code

main:
    
    PUSH {LR}
    BL _getInput
    BL _calculate
    BL _output

    POP {PC}

_getInput:
    
    PUSH {LR}
    BL _displayPrompt

    SUB SP, SP, #4          @ create word on stack

    LDR R0, addr_format     @ get the address of the the input entered by user
    MOV R1, SP              @ copy as parameter
    BL scanf

    LDR R1, [SP]            @ load the data from memory address of SP into R1
    LDR R2, addr_iterations @ load the address of iterations into R2
    STR R1, [R2]            @ store data from R1 into iterations
    ADD SP, SP, #4

    POP {PC}

_displayPrompt:
    
    PUSH {LR}
    LDR R0, =prompt

    BL printf

    POP {PC}

_calculate:
    
    LDR R0, addr_product
    LDR R0, [R0]
    LDR R1, addr_iterations
    LDR R1, [R1]                    @ Load the iteration counter
    MUL R0, R0, R1                  @ R0 *= R1 / product = product * counter
    SUBS R1, R1, #2             @ R1-- / counter = counter - 1

    LDR R2, addr_iterations         @ write back
    LDR R3, addr_product            @ address of where to store the result
    STR R0, [R3]                    @ store the final product back into addr_product
    STR R1, [R2]                    

    MOVLE PC, LR                    @ go back to main once the variable interations is 0 / return
    BGT _calculate                  @ continue looping as long as not 0

    
_output:
    
    PUSH {LR}
    LDR R0, addr_message
    LDR R1, addr_product
    LDR R1, [R1]

    BL printf

    POP {PC}

addr_format: .word scanformat

addr_iterations: .word iterations

addr_product: .word product

addr_message: .word message

.data

    prompt: .asciz "Enter a positive integer number: "
    scanformat: .asciz "%d"
    iterations: .word 1
    product: .word 1
    message: .asciz "Result: %d\n"
```

Comment: pass a 3rd arg to printf, in r2, just like you would in C.  (With a format string to match, of course). https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: And change the format string to `"Result of %d = %d\n"`

Comment: That means under _ouput, add "LDR R2, addr_format" and then "LDR R2, [R2]" before BL printf?

Comment: Surely you mean `add_iterations`? And the `iterations` value should go into `R1`, while the `product` value should go into `R2`. since that's the order that you want them printed in.

Comment: i got -1 when i changed it to add_iterations and not 5 when i keyed in 5